# "Cannot update during existing date transition" using react-navigation with redux in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have just started learning react-native and redux. I am trying to implement authentication scenario. I am using `react-navigation`.

```
import { authenticate } from './../actions';

const Component = (props) => {
  const { dispatch, user } = props;

  // user comes from state (using mapStateToProps)

  let phone = '';
  let password = '';

  if (user.errors != null) {
    alert(user.errors);
  }

  if (user.authenticated) {
      dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoggedIn' }));
  }

  async function onLogin() {    
    dispatch(authenticate(phone, password));
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, width: '100%', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 10}}
        placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xx-xx"
        keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
        onChangeText={(value) => phone = value}
        value={phone}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, width: '100%', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 10}}
        placeholder="Пароль"
        onChangeText={(value) => password = value}
        value={password}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={onLogin}
        title="Continue"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is authenticate action

```
export function authenticate(phone, password) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(authenticating());
    let response;
    try {
      response = await Api.authenticate(phone, password);
    }
    catch (e) {
      dispatch(authenticateFailure(e.error));
      return;
    }
    dispatch(authenticateSuccess(response.token, response.payload));
  };
};
```

So basically when `authenticate` action is dispatched and user is authenticated successfully, I want to redirect user to next screen (`LoggedIn`). But after redirection I get this error:

`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.`

I guess problem is that previous component is interrupted being rendered when it is redirecting to next component (LoggedIn), because every dispatch triggers rerender.

How do I navigate to another screen after action is dispatched? Can I somehow dispatch an action without triggering rerender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try move all of this to

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   // check props you want to use as execution trigger 
 }
```

#

```
const { dispatch, user } = props;

// user comes from state (using mapStateToProps)

let phone = '';
let password = '';

if (user.errors != null) {
  alert(user.errors);
}

if (user.authenticated) {
    dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoggedIn' }));
}

async function onLogin() {    
  dispatch(authenticate(phone, password));
}
```

you might need to adapt some const you use inside render method

Comment: This doesn't work. `componentWillMount` is executed only once, but I need to catch updated state. There should be another way. I also would like to use function-based components, not class-based.

Comment: ah i see, then you can put it on componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: you can also check the specific props you want to set to trigger the specific behavior

Comment: This seems to work. I get strange behaviour, but error goes away at least. Is there a way I can do the same with function-based component like in my example?

Comment: You should also add await to your async function, is the authenticate func is asynchronous?

Comment: It is an async reducer, but function itself returns another function

Comment: Maybe you can share your action, so i can get better idea.